# Windows 10 freezes outside of safe mode

Tags: windows-10, freeze

Since this morning I've got the problem that my Windows 10 computer does not work anymore unless I run it in safe mode.

A few seconds after start-up (on the desktop) the computer completely freezes.
Not responding to the mouse/keyboard input, system time freezes and the only way to do anything is holding down the power button to force a shutdown.

There are no fancy settings changed in the UEFI Bios and the system runs indefinitely in safe mode.

Things I've done trying to fix it (in safe mode):

- Deactivated all autostart programs in task manager
- checked SSD&HDD health with CrystalDiskInfo
- checked temperature of hardware under stress test
- uninstalled GPU drivers
- run Malwarebytes

I've uninstalled the GPU drivers but it seems that it is automatically reinstalling the drivers on startup because they are still (or again) installed after a restart.

Additonally the windows settings close themselves if I click on the "Update and Security" Tab, which I don't no if that's normal for safe mode.

The Windows Build is 17763.rs5_release.180914-1434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to
disable more startups. If this helps, re-enable until finding the problematic
product.

If this doesn't help, consider using Safe Mode with Networking for creating
a Windows boot media to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Thank you my computer does not freeze anymore, now I only need to figure out which startups I have to enable again and how so that my mouse and keyboard work again.