# USB devices not working in Windows but in Bios

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, cmd.exe

I've had the problem that my Windows 10 would freeze seconds after startup, followed by an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1525625/windows-10-freezes-outside-of-safe-mode/1525628#1525628) to a question I asked yesterday. I've used Autoruns to disable all startups and this fixed the problem that Windows would basically freeze instantly after boot, but now I can't use any input device in Windows anymore.

I didn't know that you could disable the USB devices with Autoruns and now my current OS is basically bricked:

- I can't upgrade Windows to keep all files and apps because an upgrade works only from within Windows itself (where my HIDs aren't working).
- I can't use a PS/2 mouse because my motherboard does not have a PS/2 input.

The only way I can currently do anything with the computer is to boot a USB with Windows installation media and use the WindowsPE cmd.exe under computer repair options (Windows Preinstallation Environment).

- I've loaded the USB drivers for my motherboard onto the same USB I boot from and tried to run `setup.exe`, which says that it's not compatible with the running windows version. 
  Additionally, I tried to install the two `.inf` drivers I found in the driver install folder directly, but `pnputil` says the operation was successful and it doesn't fix the problem.

  ```powershell
  Pnputil -i -a "asmthub3.inf" & Pnputil -i -a "asmtxhci.inf"
  ```
- I've loaded `devcon.exe` onto the boot USB and issued `devcon hwids* > hwids.txt`, which gave me a list of 123 devices including some USB and HID devices. After that, I simply issued `devcon enable USB*`, which showed the message that it enabled a few USB devices, including USB 3.0 Root Hubs or something similar; this also didn't fix the problem.

I'm not really comfortable to do more with `devcon`, as it seems way too powerful for someone like me who doesn't really know what he's doing.

- I've also loaded Autoruns onto the boot USB and ran `autorunsc64.exe`, but this only gives me a few entries from the `X:\` (`userinit.exe`, `SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe`, `cmd.exe` x2, `shell32.dll`, `IconCodecService.dll`), even though the boot USB is `E:\`, Windows is on `C:\`, and my storage HDD is `D:\`.

---

Is there some way I can enable my USB/HID devices again without making a new clean install of Windows 10?

Comment: What mainboard is used in your PC? Have yu tried each and every USB port available (sometimes the ports are connected to different chips and only one may be non-working). In any way you can "reinstall" Windows 10 over your existing installation keeping all programs and documents. Only the hardware stack should be replaced.

Comment: What does Device Manager show, as it sounds like a driver issue?  Before doing a Repair Install of Windows, you can try repairing Windows first by issuing the following in an admin prompt and in the order listed (while booted to Windows and with an internet connection): `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` > `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` > reboot > `sfc /scannow` > reboot.  A Repair Install is done by running Windows Setup's `setup.exe` _while booted to Windows_.

Comment: @Robert "asus rog crosshair vi hero", I've tried every usb port and looked if the capslock indicator would turn on, which didn't work.
And I can't upgrade Windows 10 because that works only if the setup is executed from within Windows, which I can't because I have no way of input in Windows.

Comment: @JW0914 I don't know how to access Device Manager from WindowsPE cmd  and `dism /online` does not work in WindowsPE or rather with DISM does appear to only work to fix the WindowsPE on the boot USB not my Windows 10 on C:\

Comment: For Device Manager, you have to boot to Windows (are you unable to do so?). You can run the `DISM` commands from WinPE/WinRE, but it's preferred to do so while booted to Windows, as `/RestoreHealth` requires a source to compare against, which is normally the Windows Update servers.  If you can't boot to Windows: `dism /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` > `dism /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth` > `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=C:\ /offwindir=C:\Windows` > Reboot

Comment: @JW0914  `ism /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` give me Error 32 and a really long dism.log which has multiple warning and error messages saying it cannot determin OS version, can't find files, etc....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104531/discussion-between-gittinggud-and-jw0914).

Comment: @JW0914 I've uploaded the dism and cbs logs to pastebins and posted them in our chat.

Comment: @JW0914 Streamlined install.esd and sfc both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you had System Restore enabled, you could go back in time to before
you did the Autoruns manipulation.

Since you can boot from USB, choose
*Repair your computer > Advanced options > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > System Restore*.

For more information with screenshots see
[How to use System Restore on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10).

Comment: And if there is no system restore point?

Comment: If I try to select a system restore point manually I can choose to install a driver for a device which give me a gui file browser with access to all drives and files. Is there any way I can undo the Autoruns manipulation this way? I can even run Autoruns64.exe this way but it seems to only change settings for the WindowsPE environment from the boot USB not my Windows 10 OS

Comment: @GittingGud That driver install option is only for RAID drivers and only appears if you select restore from a system image, not System Restore.  You can execute System Restore from WinPE/WinRE via `rstrui`

Comment: @JW0914 the option may only be supposed to be for RAID drivers but the gui file explorer it gives me to select those drivers can be used for other stuff, can it not? If I'm able to run Autruns64 (the gui version) inside of WindowsPE thanks to the file explorer, can't I do a lot of stuff from there? And System Restore isn't useful if I don't have a Restore point, right?

Comment: If you can get Autoruns to work, use the menu *File > Analyze Offline System* to work on the disk C drive (which may now be called D).

Comment: @harrymc I figured that out and selected my OS drive (now F), enabled everything clicked the save icon, rebooted but it does not seem to chance anything. Which is new is that now all entries in Autoruns are red which they weren't before and if I click on the entries it says that the file cannot be found, even though I can find them F:\windows\system32\drivers\

Comment: Not having System Restore enabled is a problem. You are now approaching Windows re-installation, but hopefully it will detect the existing installation and only do an upgrade. Ensure that your installation USB is of the latest Windows 10 version.

Comment: @GittingGud Sole purpose of WinRE's driver install option is to install RAID drivers - selecting other drivers will do nothing. Again, **System Restore _does not_ have an option for installing drivers**; the option to restore from a system image does (_they're not the same things)_; please review the Microsoft Docs.  Easiest way to solve your problem is to boot to Windows _(I'm unsure why you're trying to troubleshoot this in WinPE/WinRE)_, run the commands in the order I listed above, and if that doesn't solve it, perform a Repair Install as detailed in my first comment under your question.

Comment: @JW0914 You don't get my point about the file explorer: I'm able to launch different programs (which run in WinPE) from there.. And I can boot into Windows but how am I gonna start cmd.exe and run those commands without any way of user input? And a repair install is only doable in Windows but again how am I gonna start the setup.exe and select Repair Install without any way of user input? I am honestly thankful for your efforts but it seems to me that you don't understand the core of this problem: *I don't have ANY user input in Windows*

Comment: @GittingGud Please specifically state that in your question (the keyboard is also not recognized - a critical piece of information)_.

Comment: @JW0914 It is: *... now I can't use any input device in Windows anymore.*